# How to make Android not to recycle my Bitmap until I don't need it?

Tags: android, bitmap, garbage-collection

I'm getting drawing cache of the view, that is set as contentView to the Activity. Then I set new content view to the activity and pass that drawing cache to it. But Android recycles my bitmaps and I'm getting this exception:

> 06-13 01:58:04.132: E/AndroidRuntime(15106): java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@40e72dd8

Any way to fix it? I had an idea to extend Bitmap class, but it's final. Why GC is recycling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, I just cloned the bitmap to new. I think, exception occurred because the cached view was removed with it's drawing cache.

Answer (score 2):

A bitmap being recycled does not mean it was Garbage Collected, it means `Bitmap.recycle()` was called on it, on purpose. I'm not familiar with the specific code, but I'm pretty sure that when you call `setContentView()` with something new, it will tear down the previous views (since it's assumed that you don't want them anymore). It seems to be hitting an `ImageView` and that calls `recycle()` on its Bitmap to be a good citizen, which then gives you your error. My guess is that what you're trying to do is not supported.